# Convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\arctan(x) \mathop{d}x$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to prove that integral
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\arctan(x) \mathop{d}x$$
converges (or does not)?

Comment: What sort of convergence are you looking for here? It converges conditionally but not absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the integral converges since

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}\arctan x\sim_\infty\frac \pi2\frac{\sin x}{x}$$
and the integral

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$
exists (using an integration by parts).

Comment: Could you say how you use integration by parts in this question?

Comment: What kind of integral convergence test did you use? Can you prove a link to its description? I think earlier that this test only works for positive functions.

Comment: $$\int_1^A \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=-\frac{\cos x}{x}\bigg|_1^A-\int_1^A\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx$$
and pass to the limit $A\to\infty$ @mfl

Comment: I would complete this answer by using the fact : $\frac{\pi}{2}-arctan(x) = arctan(\frac{1}{x})$. Then use an expansion of $arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ to prove that the integral indeed converges